# mongoosejs-how to create TTL index with given parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongo TTL index, and what I want to achieve is to create a TTL index with specified parameters. And I have already known how to create TTL index with hardcoded data when creating the schema, like below:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const { Schema } = mongoose

const VipUserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  // timestamp of the creation data of the user
  { timestamps: true },
)

VipUserSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30, partialFilterExpression: { username: { $eq: 'xxx' } } })

// const VipUser = mongoose.model('VipUser', VipUserSchema, 'VipUsers')
export default mongoose.model('VipUser', VipUserSchema, 'VipUsers')
// export { VipUser, VipUserSchema }
```

Until now, everything works fine.

But, I need the `expireAfterSeconds` and username of `partialFilterExpression` to be passed in as parameters for certain fields and I will need more than 1 indice. So I export the schema `export { VipUser, VipUserSchema }`  and use it somewhere else as:

```
await VipUserSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30, partialFilterExpression: { username: { $eq: 'xxx' } } })
```

But it does not create the partial index as before. What should I do? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve the issue by adding

```
expireAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      expires: 0,
    },
```

to my schema, and set it when needed

```
const newVipUser = new VipUser({ username: user.username, expireAt: Date.now() + vipDuration * 1000 })
```

And actually, the `expireAt` creates an ttl index behind the scene, it can be verified by checking mongodb